# Find the lim sup and lim inf of each of the following

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

just wanted to make sure I understood what I'm doing here.

---

1. a. $5+(-1)^n$

Since -1 alternates between -1 and 1, then the smallest $a_n$ can be as $n->inf$
is 5-1 = 4, and the largest (sup) it can be is 5+1 = 6.

b. $5+(-2)^n$

$-2^n$ is either $\infty$ or $-\infty$, therefore the lim inf of $a_n$ = $-\infty$, and lim sup = $+\infty$.

c. $5+\frac{1}{n} \sin(n)$

sine is bounded between -1 and 1, and $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, therefore, the lim sup is 5, and the lim inf is 5?

2. Let ${a_n}$ = 1 if $n=2^k$ for some positive integer $k$, and $a_n=(1/n!)$ otherwise.

a. Find lim sup $a_n$ and lim inf $a_n$.

lim sup = 1. lim inf = 0.

b. find lim sup $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$

This comes out to be $\frac{1}{(1/n!)}$ for the lim sup, which is then $+\infty$.

c. Find lim sup $|a_n|^{1/n}$

this is just $1^{1/n}$, which is then 1?

Comment: You're right. You're doing well.

Comment: So all that I put are correct? These are simple questions so it's kind of embarassing if I can't even manage these simple concepts!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your conclusion about the first one is correct. Indeed, $$(-1)^{\text{even}}=\color{red}{+}1,~~(-1)^{\text{odd}}=\color{blue}{-}1$$ so $$4\leq a_n \leq6$$

[image]

For the second one, we know that for $|a|>1$ then $a^n$ may tend to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

[image]

About the third one, what happens when $n=1$. It really make the sequence to be the bigger value.i.e; $n=1$ then $a_n=5+\sin(1)<6$:

[image]

Comment: Nicely illustrated! +1

Comment: very nice! for the 3rd one, the lim sup is then 6?

Comment: I would say that the lim sup is $5+sin(1)$

Comment: @Resident hey, what did you use to make these graphs?

Comment: @segevp: dear friend, I cannot see the graphs! it is strage to me!!. But I think I did them by Maple.