# Having troubles in understanding subsequential limits: what's $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup5+\frac{1}{n} \sin(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing Baby Rudin and have some questions.

1.Let $a_n=5+\frac{1}{n} \sin(n)$ be a sequence for $n=1,2...$. Can we take $n=1$ out and form a subsequence $b_n$ with only one element $\{5+\sin(1)\}$? If yes, can we say it is the limit of $b_n$ and thus belongs to the subsequential limit set of $a_n$ and by further inspection conclude that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup a_n=5+\sin(1)$?

The link to the original post that brought up this example is listed below:
[Find the lim sup and lim inf of each of the following](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571373/find-the-lim-sup-and-lim-inf-of-each-of-the-following)

2.Another question is I don't quite understand Baby Rudin's Theorem 3.17 (b):

If $x>\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup s_n$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $s_n<x$.

Doesn't $s_n<x$ for all $n$ if $x>\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup s_n$?

Comment: I'm assuming $s_n$ is an arbitrary sequence? Sometimes $s_n$ is used for the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Yes, $S_n$ is an arbitrary sequence.

Comment: Only infinite sequences have limits.  You cannot take a single term and call it a sequence.  (You **can** have "constant sequences" but that consists of an infinite sequence of terms, all of which happen to be the same.)

Comment: @user247327 Ok. But there are finite sequences, so can't there be a single term sequence if we don't require it to have a limit？